# Missing extension method AddJwtBearerAuthentication() for IServiceCollection in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: authentication, jwt, bearer-token, .net-core-1.1, .net-core-2.0

I have updated my project from Core 1.1 to Core 2.0 using instructions from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/
(updated target framework to .NET Core 2.0 and used metapackage Microsoft.AspNetCore.All). I have updated all possible nuget packages to latest versions as well.

In .NET Core 1.1 i was adding JWT Bearer Authentication this way:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(); // from Startup.Configure()
```

As per http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-asp-net-core-2-0/ for Core 2.0 the new way is to call:

```
services.AddJwtBearerAuthentication(); // from Startup.ConfigureServices()
```

But the method **AddJwtBearerAuthentication()** is absent. The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 is installed.

New empty Core 2.0 projects (with JwtBearer package) are also does not have extension method AddJwtBearerAuthentication() for IServiceCollection.

The old method **app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication()** does not compile at all:

```
Error   CS0619  'JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder, JwtBearerOptions)' is obsolete: 'See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ConfigureServices use the following code to configure JWTBearer Authentication:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = "https://localhost:54302";
            o.Audience = "your-api-id";
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

And in `Configure` just before `UseMvc()` add `UseAuthentication()`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc();
```

For a detailed example see: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample/Startup.cs#L51

Answer (score 1):

Method that configure Jwt authentication:

```
// Configure authentication with JWT (Json Web Token).
public void ConfigureJwtAuthService(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Enable the use of an [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
  // JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
  // attribute on methods and classes to protect.
  services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.SaveToken = true;
    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
      IssuerSigningKey = JwtController.SecurityKey,
      ValidAudience = JwtController.Audience,
      ValidIssuer = JwtController.Issuer,
      // When receiving a token, check that we've signed it.
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      // When receiving a token, check that it is still valid.
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      // This defines the maximum allowable clock skew when validating 
      // the lifetime. As we're creating the tokens locally and validating
      // them on the same machines which should have synchronised time,
      // this can be set to zero.
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
    };
  });
}
```

Now inside the *ConfigureServices()* method of the *Startup.cs*,  you can call *ConfigureJwtAuthService()* method to configure the Jwt authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001/";
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
        });
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

Answer (score 0):

**.Net 7**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using PAP.Web.Helpers;
using PAP.Web.Services;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

// configure strongly typed settings object
AppSettings AppSettings = new AppSettings();

builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(AppSettings);

// Now start using it
string OauthIssuer = AppSettings.OAuthIssuer;
string OauthClientId = AppSettings.OAuthClientId;
var OauthSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(AppSettings.OAuthSecret);
 

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
        .AddCookie(cookie =>
        {
            cookie.AccessDeniedPath = "logout";
            cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
        {
            jwt.Audience = OauthClientId;
            jwt.Authority = OauthIssuer;
            jwt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            jwt.SaveToken = true;
            jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = OauthIssuer,
                ValidAudience = OauthClientId,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(OauthSecret),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                RequireAudience = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateTokenReplay = false,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
            jwt.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration();

        }); 

builder.Services.AddCon`enter code here`trollers();

// configure strongly typed settings object
//builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

// configure DI for application services
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();


var app = builder.Build();
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**AppSettings.cs**
namespace PAP.Web.Helpers;

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string OAuthIssuer { get; set; }
    public string OAuthClientId { get; set; }
    public string OAuthSecret { get; set; } 

}
```