# .Net Core 2 - How to add and use Authentication service (Jwt endpoint)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware, .net-core-2.0

I am using .Net Core 2. I need to add a simple token endpoint. I was following [this](https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-an-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-3-json-web-token) article but found that the below method is [obsolete in .Net Core 2](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310)

`app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication();`

Quoting the second link:

> Configure(): UseXyzAuthentication() has been replaced by ConfigureService(): AddXyz()

Therefore, in ConfigureService method, i am trying to use something like

`services.AddAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions());`

which is not correct, i know but how to achieve this? 
Unfortunately, i couldn't find any help on web.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are implemented some what in a more efficient manner in core 2.0 
possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712067/missing-extension-method-addjwtbearerauthentication-for-iservicecollection-in)

Comment: Thanks, that helped

Answer (score 0):

It may also explain a lot easier and technical manner. Good [solution](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2007)

Answer (score 0):

The [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) contains a whole article dedicated to the changes in Authentication and Identity:

In `Configure` you have to call `app.UseAuthentication();`.

The code in `ConfigureServices` should be:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001/";
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
    });
```